# Kafka Streams State Store range vs prefixScan

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

State stores in Kafka Streams have a range(from, to) method, where we can do a range query. Since version 2.8.0 there is also a prefixScan(prefix, serializer) method.

What is the difference between those two? By that, i mean performance wise. Is the prefixScan() method faster (or more efficient) than the range() method? And what about retrieval order, does the prefixScan() and range() differ here?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that one gets all values by a key prefix. The other gets values between two comparable keys.

Their use cases are different, so performance ultimately shouldn't matter.

I don't think order is guaranteed, but you can always sort the returned iterator on your own.

Comment: Yes i know that one accepts a from and to, and the prefix only accepts a prefix. So their use case differ. But my question was more about performance wise and the internals. Is the prefixScan using the more efficient prefix retrieval of RocksDB eliminating multiple IO's? Does the range also does this under the hood?